# Implementing/Registering OS X Service with Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to implement a simple standalone service in Swift that mutes/unmutes the system volume. That part works fine, but when I invoke the service from a hotkey or the Services menu, I get an error

Mute[36967:3258511] Cannot find service provider for selector toggleMute:userData:error: or toggleMute:: for service toggleMute

main.swift:

```
import AppKit
import AudioToolbox

class Muter {

  var muted: Bool {...}

  //Service Method
  func toggleMute(pboard: NSPasteboard, userData: String, error: NSErrorPointer) {
    println("Service mute called")
    muted = !muted
  }
}

NSRegisterServicesProvider(Muter(), "Mute")
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().run()
```

Info.plist:

```
<key>NSServices</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>Toggle Mute</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>toggleMute</string>
        <key>NSPortName</key>
        <string>Mute</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Does it work if you mark your `toggleMute` method with `@objc`?

Comment: Awesome, that did it. I had a feeling it was something about Swift/ObjC interaction, but didn't think of doing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark the `toggleMute` method with the `@objc` attribute, or the selector won't be registered with the Objective-C runtime, which is responsible for dispatching calls to your service.

Comment: In Swift 3 it's also important to omit the first argument name: func toggleMute(_ pboard: NSPasteboard, userData: String, error: NSErrorPointer)